# Regex on Presto

Tags: sql, regex, split, presto, unnest

I have data like this: `a35={"abc":"D1,9,12, 23, 24, 25, 26"}` on a column.

What I want to do is, using Presto, extract only the id (on this case `a35`) on a new column if and only if I have `"abc":"D1` on the beginning of the json.

So far I am trying to make this regex work for extracting the id, but no success, nothing returns from my query...

```
    --sample data
WITH dataset(id_str) AS (
  SELECT ('a35={"abc":"D1,9,12, 23, 24, 25, 26"}')
)

--query
SELECT regexp_extract_all(id_str, '"\b(?<id>\w{3})\=\{\"abc\"\:\"D1\,"')
FROM dataset;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A completely overkill method for this use case, but it might be useful for more advanced applications:

```
WITH dataset(id_str) AS (
    SELECT ('a35={"abc":"D1,9,12, 23, 24, 25, 26"}')
)
SELECT map_keys(
        map_filter(
            CAST(
                   json_parse(regexp_replace(id_str, '(\d|\w*)=(.*)', '{"$1":$2}') -- Converts string to valid JSON.
                ) as MAP<VARCHAR, JSON>) -- Converts JSON to MAP of JSON
            , (k,v) -> starts_with(CAST(json_extract(v, '$.abc') AS VARCHAR), 'D1')) -- Filters only the desired values
        ) as keys -- extracts the keys.
FROM dataset
```

Output:

| keys |
| --- |
| {a35} |

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! :) Why you say is overkill but useful for more advanced applications? It will run faster than the regex directly?

Comment: If your strings were more complicated than the given one, and perhaps nested, then this shows the basic framework of how to read, convert, filter, etc.  Since your string is fairly simple, there's no need for all that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer was correct, I just had two quotes more than I should on the regex. The correct answer is:

```
        --sample data
WITH dataset(id_str) AS (
  SELECT ('a35={"abc":"D1,9,12, 23, 24, 25, 26"}')
)

--query
SELECT regexp_extract_all(id_str, '\b(?<id>\w{3})\=\{\"abc\"\:\"D1\,')
FROM dataset;
```

For reference, I've validated the regex using: https://regex101.com/